# Ubuntu 18.10 dock position doesn't change

Tags: 18.10, ubuntu-dock, dock

I changed the dock position in the settings to "bottom" but it doesn't change.
No other setting is applied either (like auto hide).
Running the commands from terminal also doesn't do anything.

Any ideas?
This is a fresh installation on a Lenovo Ideapad 330.

Here's my `sudo debsums gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` output:

```
/usr/share/doc/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/changelog.gz                 OK
/usr/share/doc/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/copyright                    OK
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_ubuntu-dock.gschema.override                   OK
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock.gschema.xml OK
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/README.md            OK
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/Settings.ui          OK
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/appIconIndicators.js OK
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/appIcons.js          OK
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/convenience.js       OK
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/dash.js              OK
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/docking.js           OK
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/extension.js         OK
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/intellihide.js       OK
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/launcherAPI.js       OK
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/media/glossy.svg     OK
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/media/highlight_stacked_bg.svg OK
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/media/highlight_stacked_bg_h.svg OK
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/media/logo.svg       OK
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/metadata.json        OK
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/stylesheet.css       OK
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/theming.js           OK
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/utils.js             OK
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/windowPreview.js     OK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is not really a solution, the only thing that worked for me was switching to a different desktop environment.
This is after trying upgrading all the way up to 19.04.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've switched your dock to an extension, instead of default ubuntu dock.

Have you tried gnome-tweaks?

```
apt install gnome-tweaks
```

In `Extensions` menu you can disable any custom dock extensions to make sure that the default is used.

Then you can try to switch its position via terminal using:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-position BOTTOM
```

Make sure it's set with:

```
gsettings list-recursively  | grep org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock | grep position
```

it should print:

> org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-position 'BOTTOM'

Also make sure `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` is installed:

```
dpkg -l | grep -E "^ii.*gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock"
```

You can use `debsums` to verify package integrity:

```
sudo apt install debsums
sudo debsums gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. As I said, the installation was clean - I didn't install anything else but I've gone ahead and installed gnome tweaks like you suggested, except I don't see an "Extensions" menu. Either way, I've gone through all the steps you described, I'm getting all of the outputs I'm supposed to get: `org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-position 'BOTTOM'` and `ii  gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock          63ubuntu1.18.10.2                                  all          Ubuntu Dock for GNOME Shell` respectively and the dock is still on the left side.

Comment: can you please update your question with the output from debsums (I've just updated my answer with instructions)

Comment: Debsums looks ok, please make sure that you have no extensions like dash-to-dock in `ls .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`. In case such extension exists there, remove it and reboot.

Comment: `ls: cannot access '.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/': No such file or directory` apparently I don't have a folder called gnome-shell, only gnome-software, and even there there's no directory called extensions. Either way, apart from the things you told me to install this is a fresh installation.

Comment: Sorry, no other ideas. Consider reporting it as a bug.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying :)